# Can I use Windows Server 2019 Essentials as a Stand Alone WebServer?

Tags: windows-server-2019

I looked around a lot but the only thing I find is the statement from Microsoft: "Functionality is limited on Windows Server 2019 essentials" and comparison Charts comparing the Standard and DataCenter Editions...

So what exactly is limited in Essentials? (Beside the 25 User / 50 Devices Limit)

Can I use the Essentials Edition as Stand alone WebServer (without a Domain) using IIS and maybe a SQL Server Version installed on the Server on a hardware with 64 GB RAM and a single CPU with 12 Cores? Basically there is only a single user / Admin accessing the server. So the 25 User / 50 Device Limit would be more than OK.

Update: My Question ist NOT about Licensing it is about functionality and Limits. Licencing is clear. But still, if this is not the correct Forum for such a Question I can delete it...

Comment: This is esentially a licensing question. Your assumption that the single admin user is the only one that requires a license may be wrong. If your visitors log in or submit data, then you need CALs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing. https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue

Answer (score 2):

Making long story short: No. You’ll have to provide some valid CALs and this isn’t what web server users typically have.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/product-licensing/client-access-license

P.S. Get Datacenter edition. Or use FreeBSD and Apache. Both are free.

Comment: Thanks for the link - this link makes clear, that users not using services of the Server but only of the website don't need a CAL. Otherwise you would never be able to use Windows as a Webserver serving thousands of users… - My question is NOT about Licensing, ist about functionality and limits (like only up to 64 GB RAM)

Comment: I do not understand why your answer is **No**. From that link 'Specialty Server' do not need CAL. So as long as it is licensed correctly per core count then it will be fine (licensing wise). But @Markus question was about features instead of license though. I believe the correct is **Yes** to both license and features.